# Предоставление прав доступа на запись для папки (директории)

Tags: c#

Подскажите каким образом можно раздать права на запись в созданную из приложения папку для пользователей. Имеется вот такой код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Replog_v_3.Classes.Helpers
{
 public static class FilesHelper
 {
  //static string _fullPath = string.Empty;
  static readonly string _userName = "S-1-5-32-545";

  public static string ConfigPath
  {
   get
   {
    //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fullPath))
    //{
    string _fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
    if (!Directory.Exists(_fullPath))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(_fullPath);

    try
    {
     DirectoryInfo _di = new DirectoryInfo(_fullPath);
     DirectorySecurity _ds = _di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
     bool _writeAllow = false;

     AuthorizationRuleCollection _rules = _ds.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
     foreach (var item in _rules.Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>().Where(u => u.IdentityReference.Value.ToUpper() == _userName))
      _writeAllow |= (item.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Modify) == item.FileSystemRights;

     if (!_writeAllow)
     {
      _ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(_userName, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
      _di.SetAccessControl(_ds);
     }
    }
    catch { }
    //}

    return _fullPath;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

К сожалению не работает. Этот код я нашел на просторах сети, за давностью лет не помню уже где. Пробовал запускать откомпилированную программу с правами администратора - результат тот-же, то есть нулевой. Целевые платформы: MS Windows 7, MS Windows 10 (32 и 64 разряда). Моя машинка с 64-битной десяткой.

Спасибо

p.s. При удалении обвязки try .. catch возвращает ошибку: "SystemException: Установка отношений доверенности между основным доменом и доменом-доверителем не состоялась."

Comment: Главная проблема - вот тут: `catch { }`. Пока эта строчка присутствует в программе - невозможно понять в чем заключается ошибка.

Comment: Ок. Что надо сделать, чтобы устранить эту проблему?

Comment: Убрать эту строчку нафиг. И больше никогда не писать такого.

Comment: Пишет: "SystemException: Установка отношений доверенности между основным доменом и доменом-доверителем не состоялась." Что это значит, и как победить?

Comment: эту информацию надо добавить в вопрос

Comment: А что у вас с `_userName = "S-1-5-32-545";`, с таким именем в системе существует пользователь?

Comment: Это системная группа пользователей, в русской windows известная как "Пользователи". Предполагается, что данной программой будут пользоваться разные пользователи на компьютере, а в этой папке будут лежать данные, которые надо читать и писать всем. Типа общей папки

Comment: Вот это смотрели: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398398/5045688 ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov посмотрел по указанной вами ссылке код. Сильно не отличается, только один момент привел к победе: вместо конкретного указания имени пользователя, которому предоставляются права, используется объект SID. Это убрало ошибку и права на папку раздались. Неясно одно: смотрю права через проводник - права отображаются только в разделе особых разрешений.

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто учавствовал